# Mystery math bug in caption

Tags: captions

Don't know how I detailed I must get.
I'm in the environment

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{llncs}
```

with a truckload of (probably superfluous) usepackage commands

```
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[dvips]{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage[classicReIm]{kpfonts}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}  
\usepackage{microtype}  
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titling}
```

and have a figure caption

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=1]{images/heur}
  \caption{$\overrightarrow{E}$ for random $M_0$, probably optimal solution.}
  \label{fig:heur}
\end{figure}
```

The stinker here is the

```
$\overrightarrow{E}$
```

which works without problem in the main text. Curly brackets, also within math, are no problem either for my captions. Only this one throws a complaint

```
<images/heur.png, id=97, 144.54pt x 144.54pt> <use images/heur.png>
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a.
<to be read again> 
                   \crcr 
l.112 ...m $M_0$, probably optimal solution.}
```

Deleting the stinker or just for fun replacing it with the analog hat command (doing exactly the same, only hat instead of arrow) compiles without problems.

I know that LaTeX is black magic :-) but I'm not a complete n00b and this error makes no sense at all to me. Anybody got an idea what is going on here?

Comment: I get no errors if I combine your snippets. Make a small but complete example and show it together with your log. And clean up your preamble, you shouldn't use ngerman, that is outdated, use babel instead. epsfig is outdated since 20 years. And do you really still compile with latex+dvips?

Comment: you should provide an example, but failing that the standard answer to "weird errors in moving arguments" would be `\protect\overrightarrow`  do not load epsfig don't specify the main language is both english and german, don't specfy your main fonts are both txfonts and kpfonts don't load inputenc unles you have an old format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With TeX Live from 2017 to 2022 I get an error much earlier, namely

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=10000].
<argument> \bbl@tempe
                      USenglish
```

or similar ones.

The document produces your error with TeX Live up to 2016. Is it time to update?

The problem with `\overrightarrow` is that it *used to be* fragile, but since some years it no longer is. If you can't update at the moment, use `\protect\overrightarrow`. But…

1. the `ngerman` package is obsolete and deprecated
2. it makes no sense to load it if you write in English
3. `epsf` has been obsolete for about 30 years
4. loading both `txfonts` and `kpfonts` is not only redundant, but it can produce weird errors
5. I'm inclined to think that `titling` isn't compatible with `llncs`
6. `hyperref` should be loaded last (with a few exceptions, none of which appears in your truckload of packages).

The “truckload” is actually a very good word to describe it. Don't copy old preambles adding something here and there. A few packages are always loaded, for instance `amsmath` and possibly `graphicx` (but not twice with different options).

Start afresh and only add the packages you *do* need in the document. This reduces the risk of incompatibilities and strange errors.

Another instance: `amssymb` is not needed if you load either `txfonts` or `kpfonts` that cover the same set of symbols.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{llncs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % not necessary with recent LaTeX
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathdots}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[classicReIm]{kpfonts}

\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{microtype}  
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{hyperref}  

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=1]{images/heur}
  \caption{$\protect\overrightarrow{E}$ for random $M_0$, probably optimal solution.}
  \label{fig:heur}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

You can remove `\protect` when you update your TeX distribution.

Comment: The \protect did work, THX! And that's all that counts for me at the moment - I *rarely* use TeX in everyday work (i.e. if I need it for formulas), and if I now begin to rant what I specifically hate about it - SE character limit overrun :-) (Otherwise, the comments above are spot on.)